# Why doesn't it change the font size?

Tags: javascript, css, html

I've written a simple script in JavaScript to allow me to change the font size on a specific div (class) on my website, but it doesn't change it and I can't figure out why...

```
<script> //it gets the classname and set it font style to 20px
    function resizeText() {
        var x = document.getElementsByClassName("box2-li");
        x.style.fontSize="20px";
    };
</script>
```

This is the error I get when I press the button:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'fontSize' of undefined
```

Why is that?

Comment: using document.getElementsByClassName , you can get multiple elements of same classname and you are trying to set it for all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will have a collection, "Array" or elements in the variable 'x'.

You will need a for loop such as:

```
function resizeText() {
    var x = document.getElementsByClassName("box2-li");
    for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
        x[i].style.fontSize="20px";
    }
};
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it worked like a charm,between the font-size in the css file remains the same it changes after I refresh the page, it's great because I wouldn't want to modify that permanently.

Answer (score 6):

The `getElementsByClassName("box2-li");` gives ***a collection of elements*** not a single element, thus you cant change the font like `x.`

The collection is array like and can be accessed like `x[0].style.fontSize="20px";` or you can use `foreach` to iterate each element

Answer (score 0):

You have to look into you ´css´ file into the block where you define ´box2-li´ and create the fontSize variable, I think this will fix your problem

Answer (score 0):

```
x.className = "class-name-which-already-font-size-defined"
```

Above concept also can be used, result is you dont use in-line css. That is a best practice.

Answer (score 0):

I met the same problem, I suggest you use  `x[0].style.fontSize="20px";` instead of  `x.style.fontSize="20px";`

Because Document.getElementsByClassName() return a list of matching elements, *not* the element itself.so you havse to choose first one to as your target.

[MDN: Get the first element whose class is 'test'](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName#Get_the_first_element_whose_class_is_'test')